# "Cannot Subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'String' "

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

Swift 3.0

Got this error: "Cannot Subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'String' "

when I tried to loop through an array "pokemon" of Strings:

```
for x in pokemon {

    var name: String!
    name = pokemon[x]

    poke = Pokemon(name: name, pokemonId: x)

    pokemons.append(poke)
}
```

However, it worked when I wrote:

```
for x in 1..<pokemon.count {

   var name: String!
    name = pokemon[x]
    poke = Pokemon(name: name, pokemonId: x)
    pokemons.append(poke)
}
```

After researching, it seems that "for x in pokemon" makes "x" not an Int, but a String (actual array elements).
Why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first loop, you are doing

```
for x in pokemon
```

This casts each value in `pokemon` to `x`.

You don't need to subscript `pokemon[x]` as `x` is not an index, it *is* the element.

Naturally, you would get the error you got because:
- `pokemon` is an array of strings
- `x` is an element in `pokemon` (which makes it a string).

With this loop, this is happening in your code:

```
pokemon["snorlax"]
```

As arrays are subscriptable only by integer, this is invalid.

For this loop, one only needs to

```
name = x
```

to cast the value of the currently iterated element of `pokemon` to the variable.

---

In your second loop, you're iterating through an integer sequence (range).

```
for x in 1..<pokemon.count
```

The range `1..<pokemon.count` gives `x` the value of 1, 2, 3... and so on per iteration until you reach one less than the count of Pokemons in the array.

This works because you are now subscripting array `pokemon` to an integer value of `x`.

With this loop, this is happening in your code:

```
pokemon[1] // contains string "snorlax"`
```

---

Also, I'm not sure if this is a mistake in your code but starting the range at 1 means that you'll exclude the first element of a zero-indexed array, in which the first element is 0.

Comment: So is it just a rule of the "for in" loop, that if we want to get an index of elements, we should use "0..<pokemon.count"? And if we want to get each element -> "for x in pokemon"? (Yes, it was a mistake leaving the first element)

Comment: Yes, you got it. The first style of loop returns the elements itself, and the range style of loop returns indexes.